# How to do integration tests without controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I've done integration (aka "feature") tests with rspec and capybara, but I'm building a complex piece of functionality that combines various ruby classes and rails models and there is no controller or UI involved really.

I'd like to perform a series of tests that touches these various classes and models to make sure they all work together as expected.

This doesn't seem like a unit testing as these tests require that multiple objects work together.

It also doesn't seem like traditional rails "integration" tests, since I'm not navigating a UI or hitting controllers.

So what are these and how can I build and organize them in my rails app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not limited to rails' 'out of the box' set of folders or test types. You can add additional folders and basically organise them however you want. If you're just getting started and don't have many, I'd just put them in `spec/objects` or `spec/poros` (Plain Old Ruby Objects) and test them there. As the number of them grows, you'll probably want to break them up into folders - just decide on a convention that makes sense, and follow it. Once you go beyond the standard set of stuff rails gives you, there's no right or wrong answers per se - it's just "do what makes sense".

As for what type of tests they are, I'd still call them integration tests. While they're not testing the integration of your whole rails stack, they're testing the integration between several objects. Wether or not that means you put them in a `spec/integration_tests` folder or not is up to you - personally I wouldn't.

Comment: Convention-they're not what Rails considers integration tests. I might still put them there, but that's a rationalization for not.

Comment: Yes. And on top of that, for plain objects, I'll often not make a clear distinction between "integration tests" and "unit tests" as such. I'll just test all my objects. When it makes sense to stub/mock and take a more "unit" approach, I do that, and when it makes sense to leave collaborators in place and NOT mock, I do that. (Usually, I DON'T mock - but that's besides the point here). So I'll often have some unit-y style tests and some integration-y style tests in the one spec file.

Comment: BTW: Found this and though it was useful terminology... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing